# Changing/cropping different Images to the size of a dynamic resizing(according to the browser's) div

Tags: jquery, css

I'm aware that there are like one thousand threads with the same question. I'd lie if I told you that I read them all, but I certainly read A LOT of them.

My current problem is this: I currently have a div that resizes according to the size of the browser and has a footer with a "menu" at the bottom. Now, I placed some "background" images which fade in and fade out inside of the div (I use the quotations because they are not set as a css property background image because you can't use jquery transitions with it and the css3 transitions are not supported in IE). I used the `$(window).resize` to achieve this (and that way I also solved the problem of the image overstretching the div to a point the menu wouldn't show up). So far so good, the problem comes when the image does not fit the browser's width/height proportion correctly. Of course I tried using max-width, height, etc dynamically according to the screen's pixels to solve this, and to some extent it worked. I say to some extent because some images's aspect ratio are "wrong" and leave blanks at the edge of the screen when I resize them (some at height and some at width). If it would be just ONE image I would manually cut that image and make it fit. The problem is that I have LOTS of them.

My idea to solve the problem is this: Each image will leave a blank when resizing to the width of the browser OR the height of the browser. I want to resize the image to the size which WON'T leave a blank and CROP (or cut) the other part of the image that would exceed the screen's height/width.

I don't know how to achieve this. I searched for some Image cropping in jquery and found things that weren't what I wanted. Moslty to select parts of a picture... I don't know.

Any Ideas? I can answer any question or give further details about my code.

Thanks a lot!

My function that changes the images:

```
$(function() {
        $imgs = $('.bgChange'),
        imgAmount = $imgs.length;

    $($imgs.css('position', 'absolute').hide().get(0)).show();

    window.setInterval(swapImages, tiempo);

    function swapImages() {
        var $currentImg = $($imgs[current]);
        if(current == imgAmount-1) current = -1;
        var $nextImg = $($imgs[++current]),
            speed = 1500;
        $currentImg.fadeOut(speed,function(){$nextImg.fadeIn(speed);});

    }
});
```

My .bgChange class

```
.bgChange
{
margin:0;
border:0;
padding:0;
z-index:-1;
position:absolute;
}
```

My div with the images (it fits the size of the screen using some css properties that I don't understand and are in a separate file. If someone needs it I can paste them):

```
<div id="DummyFondo">
        <img class='bgChange' src="img/bg03.jpg" alt="" />
        <img class='bgChange' src="img/foto_2.jpg" alt="" />
        <img class='bgChange' src="img/Semillas2.jpg" alt="" />
         ....goes on
</div>
```

My resize function:

```
$(window).resize(function()
{
    ResizeImages();
});
```

The resizeImages method does not work, it's the one that i wanna change.. I've tried things like

```
function ResizeImages()
{

    $imgs = $('.bgChange'),
    imgAmount = $imgs.length;
    for(a = 0; a < imgAmount; a = a + 1)
    {
        var $currentImg = $($imgs[a]);
        $currentImg.css("max-width", $(window).width() + "px" + " !important;");
        $currentImg.css("max-height", $(window).height() + "px" + " !important;");
    }

}
```

And changing those things to height, width, min-width, etcetera. HERE is where I wanna put the "cropping" logic: The calculation where I decide which side to crop (and the cropping itself)

Comment: code code code, too much text...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's a little demo of what I'm about to explain, that resizes an image to fit in the **window** according to your specification (you can easily change it to fit in a `div` or any other container-element): [little link to the little demo](http://goo.gl/Ne8dO).

My idea here is that, you always resize to whatever dimension (height/width) is bigger, then, to "crop" the excess amount in the smaller dimension you have, you "pull" the positioning to the appropriate negative value. Here's the code that does the resizing in that demo:

```
function resizeImg() {
    var curimg = $('.bgChange');
    var ww = $(document).innerWidth(), hh = $(document).innerHeight();
    if(hh > ww) {
        curimg.height(hh);
        var lft = - Math.floor((curimg.width() - ww) / 2);
        curimg.css({"top":"0px", "left":lft});
    }
    else if(ww > hh) {
        curimg.width(ww);
        var tp = - Math.floor((curimg.height() - hh) / 2);
        curimg.css({"left":"0px", "top":tp});
    }
}
```

I hope that helped you in any manner! I'd be delighted to explain any part of the code if it's vague.

Comment: Flawless. I had to edit a couple of things to fit my things but I got the main idea from here =)

Answer (score 0):

What browsers do you need to support? CSS3 can sort this:

```
.backgroundDiv {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

jQuery can make this work in older browsers: http://louisremi.github.com/jquery.backgroundSize.js/demo/

Comment: From question: "(I use the quotations because they are not set as a css property background image because you can't use jquery transitions with it and the css3 transitions are not supported in IE)."

Comment: You can't use jQuery transitions on something with a background image?

Comment: No, you cannot. I think there's a method involving sprites but it's not supported in every browser =(

Comment: Are you talking about fadeIn and fadeOut? They work in IE6 =/

Comment: Let me explain further: I cannot use the background image property because the transition cannot be applied JUST to the background image, it has to be applied to the whole div. (I wasn't the one that downvoted your question though). I'm currently trying the link that you provided though. If it works for me I'll accept. Thanks a lot for your feedback =).

Comment: No worries. If you've got other things in the div that you don't want to fade, you could absolutely position another div behind the one you've already got and put the background image in that.

Comment: I'll try that (even though I've no idea how). Thanks!